# Strange behaviour of CAST() in INSERT statement

Tags: mysql

I want to migrate a bunch of varchar like '2015-01-08T00:00:00+00:00' to another table that is using datetime.

When using the CAST() function in a select statement it seems to work perfectly:

```
SELECT CAST(field_value AS datetime) FROM table
```

I retrieve 2015-01-08 00:00:00;

But when trying to do the INSERT statement I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2015-01-08T00:00:00+00:00'
```

It seems like the cast function it's not working on the insert statement. The insert statement I'm using is of type:

```
  INSERT INTO new_table
    SELECT t.x, t2.x, CAST(t2.field_value AS datetime), t.y
    FROM table t
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t2.id = t.t2_id
    WHERE t2.field_value !='';
```

EDITED:

[link to sqlfiddle that reproduces the issue](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5eff62/2)

The SELECT statement in the fiddle gives me a different result than in local (both workbench and command line).

Tried using CONVERT() and I get the same problem

How do I properly insert the dates strings into the new_table table?

Comment: You're missing the table name after `INSERT INTO`.

Comment: You're also missing the `ON` clause after `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48704/mysql-5-6-datetime-incorrect-datetime-value-2013-08-25t1700000000-with-er

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Barmar I edited the file and created an sql fiddle as you proposed. Still haven't figure out the problem

Answer (score 0):

Because of strict mode:

[mysql error when using cast in update statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142273/mysql-error-1292-when-using-cast-in-update-statement?rq=1)

Still don't understand why I didn't get any warnings on the SELECT statement though.

Comment: Warnings aren't displayed by default, you have to use `SHOW WARNINGS` to see them.